# Power in survival analysis

Tags: survival, statistical-power

I just read an article discussing the effect of radiotherapy duration on survival. They state the following:

> It was expected that changing the treatment from 1 week to 3 weeks
>   would improve survival by 15%. 144 deaths were needed to detect a
>   hazard ratio of 1.61 between the two treatment arms, with a power of
>   80% and a significance level of 5%.

Could someone elaborate on how this poweranalysis was done, specifically where does the number 1.61 come from?

Reference to the article:

Pubmed PMID: 26392096

Comment: Can you provide a full citation for the article?

Answer (score 0):

The [cited paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1200/JCO.2015.62.6606) reported on a non-inferiority trial for 1 week versus 3 weeks of radiotherapy in elderly/frail patients with glioblastoma multiforme.

The confusion here might arise from the ambiguity in the phrase "improve survival by 15%." To me, that seems to represent a *15 percentage point* improvement from a baseline of 6-month median (50%) survival.

For an exponential survival curve with $S(t)=\exp(-t/\beta)$, a median survival of 6 months means $\beta = 8.656$ months. If you multiply that value of $\beta$ by 1.61, getting a value of 13.94 months, the corresponding 6-month survival is $\exp(-6/13.94)=0.65$, or 65% 6-month survival. That's a 15 *percentage point* improvement in 6-month survival.

As the cited paper was in the *Journal of Clinical Oncology*, which typically has strong statistical review, the power analysis for the non-inferiority trial presumably followed guidelines like those  in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.bbmt.2008.10.004), although I haven't worked through the details myself.